# Wordpress select image from Media Library

Tags: wordpress, media-library

I create one theme for wordpress and on admin panel, I need to select image (Logo) from media library by admin site. I use this code but not work:

```
<?php
add_action ('admin_enqueue_scripts', function() {
    if(is_admin())
    wp_enqueue_media(); 
});
?>
<form method="post">
    <input type="text" class="process_custom_images" id="process_custom_images" name="selected_logo" value="" placeholder="http://">
    <button class="set_custom_logo button" style="vertical-align: middle;">Select Logo</button>
</form>

<script>
//“Add Media” button
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var $ = jQuery;
    if ($('.set_custom_logo').length > 0) {
        if ( typeof wp !== 'undefined' && wp.media && wp.media.editor) {
            $(document).on('click', '.set_custom_logo', function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var button = $(this);
                var id = button.prev();
                wp.media.editor.send.attachment = function(props, attachment) {
                    id.val(attachment.url);
                };
                wp.media.editor.open(button);
                return false;
            });
        }
    }
});
</script>
```

But when I insert below code inside `form` tag, above code working well.

```
<div><?php wp_editor("", 'postcontent', $settings = array('textarea_rows'=> '10')); ?></div>
```

But I don't need text editor!
Please help me.
Thank's

Comment: So do you want logo to appear anywhere in admin panel or your front end?

Comment: @divy3993 Thx, I have one form on theme setting page in admin panel and admin site after login, can change site logo on theme setting page

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all `wp_enqueue_media();` should be in your functions.php file and should look something like this:

```
function misha_include_script() {
    if ( ! did_action( 'wp_enqueue_media' ) ) {
        wp_enqueue_media();
    }
}

add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'misha_include_script' );
```

Second, the jQuery call in admin area is optimal to begin this way:

```
jQuery(function( $ ){

    // your jQuery is here

});
```

I recommend to try the above tips, if it doesn't help, I hope this tutorial will be useful for you https://rudrastyh.com/wordpress/customizable-media-uploader.html

Answer (score 0):

You should use **wp.media** to use the WordPress Media Manager dialog.
First, you need to enqueue the scripts:

```html
// As you are dealing with plugin settings,
// I assume you are in admin side
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'load_wp_media_files' );
function load_wp_media_files( $page ) {
  // change to the $page where you want to enqueue the script
  if( $page == 'options-general.php' ) {
    // Enqueue WordPress media scripts
    wp_enqueue_media();
    // Enqueue custom script that will interact with wp.media
    wp_enqueue_script( 'myprefix_script', plugins_url( '/js/myscript.js' , __FILE__ ), array('jquery'), '0.1' );
  }
}
```

Your HTML could be something like this (note my code use attachment ID in the plugin setting instead of image url as you did in your answer, I think it is much better. For example, using ID allows you to get different images sizes when you need them):

```html
$image_id = get_option( 'myprefix_image_id' );
if( intval( $image_id ) > 0 ) {
    // Change with the image size you want to use
    $image = wp_get_attachment_image( $image_id, 'medium', false, array( 'id' => 'myprefix-preview-image' ) );
} else {
    // Some default image
    $image = '<img id="myprefix-preview-image" src="https://some.default.image.jpg" />';
}

  echo $image; ?>
 <input type="hidden" name="myprefix_image_id" id="myprefix_image_id" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $image_id ); ?>" class="regular-text" />
 <input type='button' class="button-primary" value="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Select a image', 'mytextdomain' ); ?>" id="myprefix_media_manager"/>
```

**myscript.js**

```js
jQuery(document).ready( function($) {

      jQuery('input#myprefix_media_manager').click(function(e) {

             e.preventDefault();
             var image_frame;
             if(image_frame){
                 image_frame.open();
             }
             // Define image_frame as wp.media object
             image_frame = wp.media({
                           title: 'Select Media',
                           multiple : false,
                           library : {
                                type : 'image',
                            }
                       });

                       image_frame.on('close',function() {
                          // On close, get selections and save to the hidden input
                          // plus other AJAX stuff to refresh the image preview
                          var selection =  image_frame.state().get('selection');
                          var gallery_ids = new Array();
                          var my_index = 0;
                          selection.each(function(attachment) {
                             gallery_ids[my_index] = attachment['id'];
                             my_index++;
                          });
                          var ids = gallery_ids.join(",");
                          jQuery('input#myprefix_image_id').val(ids);
                          Refresh_Image(ids);
                       });

                      image_frame.on('open',function() {
                        // On open, get the id from the hidden input
                        // and select the appropiate images in the media manager
                        var selection =  image_frame.state().get('selection');
                        var ids = jQuery('input#myprefix_image_id').val().split(',');
                        ids.forEach(function(id) {
                          var attachment = wp.media.attachment(id);
                          attachment.fetch();
                          selection.add( attachment ? [ attachment ] : [] );
                        });

                      });

                    image_frame.open();
     });

});

// Ajax request to refresh the image preview
function Refresh_Image(the_id){
        var data = {
            action: 'myprefix_get_image',
            id: the_id
        };

        jQuery.get(ajaxurl, data, function(response) {

            if(response.success === true) {
                jQuery('#myprefix-preview-image').replaceWith( response.data.image );
            }
        });
}
//And the Ajax action to refresh the image preview:

// Ajax action to refresh the user image
add_action( 'wp_ajax_myprefix_get_image', 'myprefix_get_image'   );
function myprefix_get_image() {
    if(isset($_GET['id']) ){
        $image = wp_get_attachment_image( filter_input( INPUT_GET, 'id', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT ), 'medium', false, array( 'id' => 'myprefix-preview-image' ) );
        $data = array(
            'image'    => $image,
        );
        wp_send_json_success( $data );
    } else {
        wp_send_json_error();
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```